# Make apache james accept incoming mail addressed to any subdomain

Tags: james, apache-james

I have an apache james server and am using the following in the domainlist.xml:

```
<domainlist class="org.apache.james.domainlist.jpa.JPADomainList">
   <autodetect>true</autodetect>
   <autodetectIP>true</autodetectIP>
   <defaultDomain>localhost</defaultDomain>
   <domainnames>
     <domainname>foo.bar.com</domainname>
   </domainnames>
</domainlist>
```

Currently if I send mail into this james server addressed to a@foo.bar.com the mail is accepted.  If I send something to a@baz.bar.com the mail is rejected.  If I added an additional domain as follows:

```
<domainname>baz.bar.com</domainname>
```

the email to a@baz.bar.com is accepted.  What I really want is some way to get the james server to just accept mail given to any subdomain of bar.com, although I would also be okay with it accepting anything.

I went through all of the configurations in fetchmail.xml and set "reject" to be "false" for everything except the blacklist filter, but that did not allow my a@baz.bar.com email to get through.

I am running the default configurations, with the addition of a new class at the head of the processor chain:

```
  <processors>
    <processor state="root" enableJmx="true">
       <mailet match="All" class="test.LogIncoming" />
```

This LogIncoming just prints a bunch of details about the email to the log, but it isn't getting called when the inbound email's "to" domain isn't in the domainlist.xml.

I thought it might work to make a custom implementaiton of the DomainList class, but I was hoping that there might exist something that will allow a wildcard subdomain.